# Inductive Sensor Causes Print To Stop

Tags: marlin, inductive-sensor

Just added inductive sensor to my printer (`MKS Gen L Board`) using `Marlin 1.1.9`
After some tweaking it works great!
The problem is when it starts print the sensor detects the bed and stops the print because it gets triggered.

Can I tell Marlin to ignore the Z-min readings while printing?

Comment: Are you using the sensor as a normal endstop or did you modify the firmware to enable automatic bed levelling?

Comment: i was able to solve it, here is my Configuuration.h file https://bitbucket.org/OrAzran/marlin_sxw1/src/pinda/Marlin/Configuration.h

Comment: Great! Please post the solution as an answer. Copy the interesting parts of the configuration file in the answer. This may help other users with the same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem, I was missing this line:

```
#define ENDSTOPPULLUP_ZMIN_PROBE
```

Apparently the sensor required a pull-up to better define the signal.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer! I removed the link to the configuration, the pull-up hint should be sufficient for a self-contained answer. Also, linking to external content is usually not very wise as all things on the internet die from link rot eventually.